# Python cannot receive the result from cuda ctypes

Tags: python, c++, cuda, ctypes

cuda script

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

# define DELLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)


__global__ void MatAdd (const double *cellbox, const double *verticess, double *C,
                    const double *halfcells,int rows, int cols)
{


    int cellboxidy = threadIdx.y;
    int verticessidx = threadIdx.x;

    const double mincell [3] = {cellbox[cellboxidy * 3] - 
halfcells[0],cellbox[cellboxidy * 3 + 1] - halfcells[1],cellbox[cellboxidy * 3 + 2] - 
halfcells[2]};
    const double maxcell [3] = {cellbox[cellboxidy * 3] + 
halfcells[0],cellbox[cellboxidy * 3 + 1] + halfcells[1],cellbox[cellboxidy * 3 + 2] + 
halfcells[2]};

    if (verticess[verticessidx * 3] >= mincell[0] && verticess[verticessidx * 3] <= 
maxcell[0]  && verticess[verticessidx * 3 + 1] >= mincell[1]  &&  verticess[verticessidx 
* 3 + 1] <= maxcell[1] && verticess[verticessidx * 3 + 2] >= mincell[2] && 
verticess[verticessidx * 3 + 2] <= maxcell[2]){
    
        C[cellboxidy * 3] = 1;
        C[cellboxidy * 3 + 1] = 1;
        C[cellboxidy * 3 + 2] = 1;

    }

}

DELLEXPORT void twodarray (double *out , double *celb ,double *ve , double *hfc , 
double *sizecellbox , double *sizeverticess)
{    


    double cellbox [24] = {0};


    for(int i = 0 ; i<int(*sizecellbox) ; i++){
        cellbox[(i*3)] = celb[(i*3)];
        cellbox[(i*3) + 1] = celb[(i*3) + 1];
        cellbox[(i*3) + 2] = celb[(i*3) + 2];


    }



    double verticess [24] = {0};
    //cout<<int(*sizeverticess)<<endl;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<int(*sizeverticess) ; i++){
        verticess[(i*3)] = ve[(i*3)];
        verticess[(i*3) + 1] = ve[(i*3) + 1];
        verticess[(i*3) + 2] = ve[(i*3) + 2];

    }



    const int N = *sizecellbox;
    int M = *sizeverticess;


    double halfcells[3] = {};

    halfcells[0] = hfc[0];
    halfcells[1] = hfc[1];
    halfcells[2] = hfc[2];


    double *C;
    double *cellbox_d = 0, *verticess_d = 0 , *halfcells_d = 0 , *C_d = 0;
    int rows = N;
    int cols = M;

    dim3 blockDim(*sizecellbox, *sizeverticess);


    C = (double *)malloc (sizeof(*C)*100);
    cudaMalloc ((void**) &C_d, sizeof(*C_d)*100);
    cudaMalloc ((void**) &cellbox_d, sizeof(*cellbox_d)*100);
    cudaMalloc ((void**) &verticess_d, sizeof(*verticess_d)*100);
    cudaMalloc ((void**) &halfcells_d, sizeof(*halfcells_d)*3);

    cudaMemcpy (cellbox_d, cellbox, sizeof(*cellbox_d)*100, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy (verticess_d, verticess, sizeof(*verticess_d)*100, 
cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy (halfcells_d, &halfcells, sizeof(*halfcells_d)*3, 
cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    MatAdd<<<1,blockDim>>>(cellbox_d, verticess_d, C_d, halfcells_d  , rows, cols);

    cudaMemcpy (C, C_d, sizeof(*C)*100, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0 ; i<24 ; i++){
        cout<<C[i]<<endl;
    }
    out = C;

    cudaFree (cellbox);
    cudaFree (verticess_d);
    cudaFree (C_d);
    cudaFree(halfcells_d);
    free (C);
 }
 //nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -shared -o 2darray3.dll 2darray3.cu
```

python script

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from ctypes import * 

def get_cuda_square():
    dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\Ali\\Desktop\\test9\\cuda_remember\\with 
link python\\2darray3.dll") 
    func = dll.twodarray
    func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double), 
POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double) , POINTER(c_double)] 
    return func

__cuda_square = get_cuda_square()

size = int(24)

cellbox_array = [[-0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434] , 
[0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434] , 
[-0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434] , 
[0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434],[-0.35263609886169434, 
-0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434] , [0.35263609886169434, -0.35263609886169434, 
0.35263609886169434],[-0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434] , 
[0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434, 0.35263609886169434]]
cellboxsize = c_double(len(cellbox_array))

verticess_array = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] , [0.4, 0.5, 0.6] ,[0.7, 0.8, 0.9] , [0.10, 0.11, 
0.12],[0.13, 0.14, 0.15] , [0.16, 0.17, 0.18],[0.19, 0.20, 0.21] , [0.22, 0.23, 0.24]
verticesssize = c_double(len(verticess_array))

hfc_array = [1.7546,1.4456,1.4545544]
cellbox = np.array(cellbox_array).astype('double')
verticess = np.array(verticess_array).astype('double')
hfc = np.array(hfc_array).astype('double')
sc = np.array(cellboxsize).astype('double')
sv = np.array(cellboxsize).astype('double')

output = np.zeros(size).astype('double')

a_p = output.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
c_p = cellbox.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
v_p = verticess.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
h_p = hfc.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
sc_p = sc.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
sv_p = sv.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))


__cuda_square(a_p, c_p, v_p , h_p,sc_p , sv_p)
print(output)
```

I can't get the value in python but when I run the tests with the cuda script it returns the correct result.

for example:

correct resoult (cuda):
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

Wrong result (python):
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

I did some tests on other scripts and found that the problem is probably with determining the appropriate data type for the values, but how can I solve this problem?

thank you:)

Note: The 1's in the output are for testing, and after the script is correct, I want to replace the decimal numbers that were the goal of the algorithm with 1's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C (which is what is applicable for understanding here because of the `extern "C"` decorator), this is not a valid method to copy data from one place to another:

```
out = C;
```

That is overwriting a pointer value (which is passed by value, anyway) with another pointer value.  The modified pointer value is not seen in the calling environment due to pass-by-value mechanics, therefore the modified/proper/expected data won't be "seen" in the calling environment either.

You are already providing an allocation for `out` in the calling environment (i.e. in your python code) so the only thing necessary, according to my testing, is to replace that line with an actual data copy, such as:

```
memcpy(out, C, sizeof(C[0])*24);
```

According to my testing, that causes the all-ones output to show up in the python environment.

FWIW this issue has nothing to do with CUDA.  You would have a similar problem if you attempted that sort of data "return" even if not using CUDA at all.